# How to access x:Name-property in code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I assigned x:Name in my XAML-file to a object which can trigger a MouseDown-event.
In that event I'd like to get the x:name-attribute of the sender again.
How do I do that?

The object looks like that:

```
<ModelUIElement3D MouseDown="ModelUIElement3D_MouseDown" x:Name="trololo">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can access the `Name` property by casting the sender to a `FrameworkElement`.

Alternatively you can just use the reference object that is created by the designer, the instance name is the same as the name that you specify in the `x:Name` attribute.

The following demonstrates both options.

```
  private void ModelUIElement3D_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    var element = sender as FrameworkElement;

    if (element != null)
    {
      if (element.Name == "trololo")
      {
      }
    }

    // Or

    if (sender == trololo)
    {
    }

  }
```

Comment: Casting it to a FrameworkElement and then accessing doesn't seem to work but sender == trololo does.

Thank you!

Comment: @Hedge, the reason the cast to FrameWorkElement does not work is because the ModelUIElement3D inheritance chain does not derive from FrameworkElement. I had to go check that, but I am glad you have solution.

Answer (score 1):

The FrameworkElement-based Name property is a standard dependency property intended as a shortcut for x:Name (see [FrameworkElement.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx)).  However, many dependency objects do not derive from FrameworkElement, and yet they can still use the XAML-attached property x:Name.  To determine the x:Name at runtime of an object declared in XAML that does not derive from FrameworkElement, you can retrieve the object's attached property using GetValue, as shown here:

```
foreach(var column in gridItem.ColumnDefinitions)
{
    var name = column.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty) as string;
    if (name == "IsCheckedColumn")
        column.Width = show ? CheckUncheckColumn_VisibleWidth : Column_InvisibleWidth;
    else if (name == "DeleteColumn")
        column.Width = show ? DeleteColumn_VisibleWidth : Column_InvisibleWidth;
}
```